# how to go to the first matched row when using less

Tags: less-unix

i am using less to do a log analysis,

after i search for some string, there are a lot of match,

and then i use n or N to go through the matched lines, but sometimes i want to go the the first matched line or the last matched line, how to go there ?

[image]
i searched in google, but seems there is no answer for such a question, is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` will bring you to the first line and then `n` will bring you to the first match, using both uppercase (first `G` then `N`) will bring to the last match